# how to show or hide a table row in angular.dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am doing this:

```html
<tr ng-hide="true">
  <td>xxx</td>
</tr>
```

In angular this always hides the row in question. In angular.dart it doesn't seem to do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular Dart does not provide (yet) CSS files for the styles he uses. So be sure to include the following style in your CSS in order to benefit from ng-hide and ng-show directives:

```dart
.ng-hide, 
.ng-show {
   display: none !important;
}
```

See https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/330 for bugs reports.

Also, see http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngShow for explanation about the importance of `!important` (sic).

Comment: Why it's always so difficult to think of the simple solution? Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it only be `ng-hide`?